# SQLAlchemy Insert from modified select

Tags: sqlalchemy

How can I generate this query using SQLAlchemy's ORM layer?

```
insert into foo (a,b)
select ‘new’ as a, b
from foo
where a = ‘old’;
```

Assume I have foo already mapped to a class.

I have seen Insert.from_select, but I'm not sure how I can modify one of the fields like I'm doing in the text query.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `select()`, `where()` and `insert().from_select()` can do the job:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column, select
>>> foo = table('foo', column('a'), column('b'))
>>> print(foo.insert().from_select(['a', 'b'], 
          select(['"new" as a', 'b']).select_from(foo).where('a = "old"')))

INSERT INTO foo (a, b) SELECT "new" as a, b 
FROM foo 
WHERE a = "old"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's supposed to be `"new" as a`, not `a as "new"`.

Comment: er, `'new' as a`, but yeah I see how this goes now.  Except it's bad because `'new'` should be escaped, not quoted manually.

Comment: @NickRetallack going through the old answers. Did this one help, or should I remove it? Thanks!